# c++ TCP client and server not able to communicate on local machine

Tags: c++, tcp, winsock2

I have built a simple c++ TCP server and client using winsock. The code all compiles without error however either the server is refusing connections or my client is failing to connect properly.

The code is alot to put onto stackoverflow so here is a pastebin for the server and Client.

https://pastebin.com/ZQavPxsR - Server Code

https://pastebin.com/cLFVp2B1 - Client Code

```
    sockaddr_in clientService;
    clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
    InetPton(AF_INET, _T("127.0.0.1"), &clientService.sin_addr.s_addr);
    clientService.sin_port = htons(port);
 
    if (connect(clientSocket, (SOCKADDR*)&clientService, sizeof(clientService)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        std::cout << "Client: connect() = Failed to connect." << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        system("pause");
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Client: connect() is OK." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Client: Can start sending and reciving data... " << std::endl;
    }
```

Above is a snippet of the code that is from the client and is responsible for making the connection with the server.

```
    acceptSocket = accept(serverSocket, NULL, NULL);

    if (acceptSocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        std::cout << "Accept Failed: " << WSAGetLastError() << std::endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Accepted connection " << std::endl;
        system("pause");
        WSACleanup();
    }
```

Above is a snippet of the code that is from the server and is responsible for accepting the connection with the client.

Comment: Sorry to hear that your "TCP client and server not able to communicate on local machine", but what is your question for Stackoverflow? Stackoverflow is not a debugging service. We only answer ***specific***, technical programming questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your server is not initializing the `service.sin_port` field before calling `bind()`, so the code exhibits *undefined behavior*.  Your listening socket will end up trying to bind to whatever *random* port value was already present in the memory that the `sin_port` field occupies.  And if that value happens to be `0`, then `bind()` will choose a *random* port from Windows' available ephemeral ports.  In any case, it is very unlikely that your server is ever going to be listening on port `4679`, which is the port the client is trying to connect to.

---

On a side note, there are some other problems with your code:

- In both client and server, your calls to `InetPton()` *should* be passing in a pointer to the `sockaddr_in::sin_addr` field, not the `sockaddr_in::sin_addr.s_addr` field. It "works" only because `s_addr` is the sole data member of `sin_addr` and thus they have the same memory address. But technically, this is *undefined behavior* since `InetPton()` wants an `IN_ADDR*` not a `ULONG*`.
- Your server is not exiting if `listen()` fails, is leaking `serverSocket` whether `accept()` succeeds or fails, and is leaking `acceptSocket` if `accept()` succeeds.
- Your client is leaking `clientSocket` whether `connect()` succeeds or fails.